# Show Upload Button on Click of an Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In my html file, I have a file input that is hidden behind an image, so that when an image is clicked, the window where you search for images shows. The problem is with the submit part, I need a submit button, but I don't want it to show unless the image is clicked.

Then when the button is clicked, I want to reload the page, now with the button not showing (unless the image is clicked again, of course).

Here's my html code:

```
<form>
   <input id="file-input" type="file" file-model="formData.img" style="display: none;"/>
   <br>
   <button class="btn btn-booking" id = "uploadButton" ng-click = "changeImage(user._id)" style = "display:block; margin: 0 auto; "> Upload  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: There's no `img` in your code above, but you are probably looking to leverage [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow), [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) or [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).  Just key them to a property on your controller or `$scope` that you change on click of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS `display` property to hide the form until the image is clicked, then hide the image until the form is submitted, like so:

```js
var hiderImg = document.getElementById('hiderImg');

hiderImg.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // hide image, show form
  document.forms[0].style.display = "inline";
  hiderImg.style.display = "none";
});

document.getElementById('uploadButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // show image, hide form
  hiderImg.style.display = "inline-block";
  document.forms[0].style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#hiderImg {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#hiddenForm {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/White_domesticated_duck%2C_stretching.jpg" id="hiderImg" />
<form id="hiddenForm" onsubmit="javascript: return false;">
   <input id="file-input" type="file" file-model="formData.img" />
   <br>
   <button class="btn btn-booking" id = "uploadButton" ng-click = "changeImage(user._id)" style = "display:block; margin: 0 auto; "> Upload  </button>
</form>
```

**Note:** I added `onsubmit="javascript: return false;"` to the form just so that it won't try to submit in this example; you can remove that.

**Another note:** If you want the upload button to display under the Browse bar, remove the `display:block;` setting from the button.

Answer (score 0):

First of All put this directive to the your image:

```
ng-show="fileExist"
```

After that put this in the your controller:

```
var uplader = angular.element(document.getElementById("file-input"));
  uplader.bind("change", function(){
  if(uplader.val()){
     $scope.fileExist =true;
  }else{
    $scope.fileExist =false;
  }
  });
```

it's kind of watch in the your input file that handle visibilty of your image.